# Ошибка "NullPointerException:'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' по ссылке на объект null"

Tags: java, android

Я решил в Android Studio сделать приложение-календарь и добавить туда заметки, но при нажатии кнопки "ОК" в диалоге сохранения заметки, приложение вылетает со следующей ошибкой: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Код activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notes"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="149dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="149dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="376dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="150dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="162dp"
        android:text="@string/Notes"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView2"
        android:layout_width="296dp"
        android:layout_height="298dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="61dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="61dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="275dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Код MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
    Button notes;

    public AdView mAdView;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        notes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.notes);
        notes.setOnClickListener(this);

        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }


    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.notes:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notes.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Код activity_notes.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="Notes">
    
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="83dp"
            android:layout_height="73dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/addnote"
    
            android:onClick="addnote"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="279dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="324dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/final_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notesView"
            android:layout_width="410dp"
            android:layout_height="468dp"
            android:text=""
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/readnotes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="158dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="158dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="476dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="124dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="124dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
            android:onClick="onClickGet"
            android:text="@string/Open_notes"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Код Notes.java:

```
public class Notes extends AppCompatActivity {

    final Context context = this;
    public ImageButton button;
    public TextView final_text;
    public SharedPreferences pref;
    public EditText input_text;
    public TextView notesView;
    public final String save_key = "save note";





    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes);
        notesView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.notesView);
        button = findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
        final_text =  findViewById(R.id.final_text);

        init();}

    public void init(){
        pref = getSharedPreferences( "note",MODE_PRIVATE);
        input_text = findViewById (R.id.input_text);
        notesView.setText(pref.getString(save_key,"You haven`t got any note"));

    }





        public void addnote(View arg0) {

            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompt, null);

            //Создаем AlertDialog
            AlertDialog.Builder mDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            //Настраиваем prompt.xml для нашего AlertDialog:
            mDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            //Настраиваем отображение поля для ввода текста в открытом диалоге:
            final EditText userInput = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.input_text);

            //Настраиваем сообщение в диалоговом окне:
            mDialogBuilder
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                                    final_text.setText(userInput.getText());
                                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
                                    edit.putString(save_key,input_text.getText().toString());
                                    edit.apply();
                                }
                            })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

            //Создаем AlertDialog:
            AlertDialog alertDialog = mDialogBuilder.create();

            //и отображаем его:
            alertDialog.show();
            }

    public void onClickGet (View view){
        notesView.setText(pref.getString(save_key, defValue: "You haven`t got any note"));
    }
}
```

Код promt.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/write_the_note"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Помогите мне пожалуйста с этой ошибкой.

Comment: А вы посмотрите внимательно: к какому `EditText` вы обращаетесь в обработчике кнопки "ОК" и какое значение присвоено этой ссылке.

Comment: вы в активности Notes ставите разметку R.layout.activity_notes а пытаетесь найти элементы с другой разметки